# How to retrieve permissions of a user

Tags: centos, permissions, users

I need to discover which are the permissions of a user in a CentOS system. Is it possible to find which are the directories the user can access and the command he can execute? It doesn't refer to ACL's.

Comment: You would have to look at using the find command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have log for ACL ..?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417688/do-we-have-log-for-acl)

Comment: @roaima Not really since the question does not mention ACLs.

Comment: i think Kusalananda's answer is perfect. I can adapt it in according to specific needs. thanks

Comment: What, exactly, are you saying by your edit?   Are you saying that you’ll accept an answer that gives wrong results if the system has ACLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to execute a file, the file must

1. Be owned by the user and be executable by the user, or
2. Belong to the same group as the user and be executable by that group, or
3. Be executable by "others".

The following `find` command find such files in the current directory (for the current user and their primary group only):

```
uid=$( id -u ) # the user's ID
gid=$( id -g ) # the primary group ID

find . -type f \( \
    \( -user "$uid" -perm -0100 \) -o \
    \( -group "$gid" -perm -0010 \) -o \
    -perm -0001 \) -print
```

`-0100` means "at least executable by user", and `-0010` and `-0001` are the equivalent for "group" and "others".

The same criteria holds or accessibility of folders (if I'm not entirely mistaken), so changing `-type f` to `-type d` should give you the accessible folders. One may additionally want to check the folders for the "read" bit too, obviously (`-0500`, `-0050` and `-0005` *instead of* the permissions above).

For folders, this may be a solution:

```
find . -type d \( \
    \( -user "$uid" -perm -0500 \) -o \
    \( -group "$gid" -perm -0050 \) -o \
    -perm -0005 -o -prune \) -print
```

I've added `-prune` at the end so that we don't descend into folders that the user wouldn't be able to access anyway.

Change the dot to a slash to search on the whole system.

---

It's also easy to turn it around to only print the names of e.g. folders that the user *can't* access:

```
find . -type d \( \
    \( -user "$uid" -perm -0500 \) -o \
    \( -group "$gid" -perm -0050 \) -o \
    -perm -0005 -o -print -prune \)
```

Comment: The question is somewhat vaguely / unclearly worded. (1) “command(s) [the user] can execute” arguably includes *all* executables that he owns, because he can always `chmod` them to give himself execute access — so the `-perm -0100` test might not be a real restriction. (2) It also arguably includes all executables he can *read*, because he can make a copy of them (although he wouldn’t be able to preserve setuid / setgid bits). (3) And it *doesn’t* include (interpreted) scripts to which he has *only* execute access, but not read access. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Your statement of the permission-checking algorithm is slightly flawed.  For every attempted access, the system looks at **only one** group of three bits.  It looks at the 0070 bits *only* if the user doesn’t own the file, and it looks at the 0007 bits only if the 0700 and 0070 bits don’t apply.  (4) So your command give this (fairly trivial) false positive: if `fred` owns an executable file and `chmod`s it 645, 654 or 655, then he won’t have execute access, but your `find` command will say that he does.  (5) A slightly more significant false positive:  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  if a file is owned by `george` but is in `fred`’s group, and is protected 745, then, again, `fred` won’t have execute access, but your `find` command will say that he does. (6) A more significant omission: your code doesn’t handle the fact that a user can be in multiple groups.  If a file is owned by `george` but is in one of `fred`’s secondary groups, and is protected 745, then, again, `fred` won’t have execute access, but your command will say that he does.  Conversely, if it is protected 754, then he *will* have access, but your command will say that he doesn’t (false negative).

Comment: @G-Man 1) A file without executable permissions is not an executable at that point in time. Yes, one could `chmod` it to be executable, but then again, one could do that with _any_ file. 2) An executable that he can read but not execute is not an executable, so that's ok. 3) True, it should not include non-readable scripts. Changing it to the same permissions as for the folders case would solve that.

Comment: @G-Man 4) and 5) Yes, there are cases like that too. I'll see if I can fix that during some time soon. 6) I only check the primary group. Doing the secondary groups is a matter of introducing a trivial loop.

Comment: @G-Man. thanks for you contribute. The Kusalananda's script helps me and I can change it in according to my needs. Also with your corrections/clarifications. Anyway I accept the Kusalananda's answer.